# nvd3 line graph: How to create a sorted values on interactive guideline

Tags: nvd3.js

I have a NVD3 line graph based on a json file.  It seems that the interactive guideline is sorted by the order in which each series appears in the JSON file.  Is there any way to make this tooltip sorted by y value (at any given x-value) in decending order?  One way to do this would be to manually sort the order in which the series data appears in the JSON file but I'm hoping there is perhaps some attributes in the interactiveguideline that would allow me to do this in NVD3 directly?

My html file looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="nvd3/build/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.2/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="nvd3/build/nv.d3.js"></script>


    <style>
        text {
            font: 12px sans-serif;
        }
        svg {
            display: block;
        }
        html, body, #chart, svg {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chart" class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'>
    <svg></svg>
</div>

<script>


  d3.json("distance.json",function(error,data) {
   nv.addGraph(function() {
      var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart()


            .x(function(d,i) { return d[0] })
            .y(function(d,i) {return d[1] });

        chart.xAxis.tickFormat (function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
            });
        chart.x2Axis.tickFormat (function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
            });
        chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
        chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
        chart.useInteractiveGuideline(true)
        ;


      d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart)
        ;

      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

      return chart;
  });

});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```